# Matching 1-2 digits at end of string while lookbehinding pre-defined strings with digits

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, stringr

I have a character vector of ML algorithms which have 1 or 2 digits affixed at the end and which I'm trying to match (and ultimately get rid of). Problem is I have a select few algorithms which have numbers as part of their original name which I want to keep as well. For example `svmLinear2` and `C5.0`.

Example character vector:

```
algs <- c("svmLinear234", "svmLinear25", "C5.05", "C5.053", "gamSpline34", "bagEarth8")
```

First I thought about incorporating a negative lookbehind to escape the strings of the algorithms which had numbers as part of their original name:

```
algs %>% 
  str_view_all("(?<!svmLinear2|C5.0)[:digit:]{1,2}$")
```

[image]

Works fine for the algorithms which don't have digits in their name originally, but doesn't seem to work with the algorithms which I tried to negatively lookbehind for.

I tried a positive lookbehind to see how this would effect the matching (knowing it wouldn't work for `gamSpline34` or `bagEarth8`):

```
algs %>% 
  str_view_all("(?<=svmLinear2|C5.0)[:digit:]{1,2}$")
```

[image]

Which works perfectly for those algorithms with digits in their original name, but I don't know how to combine this regex with capturing the digits from the algorithms without any digits in their original name.

I'm trying to combine these two regexs somehow but I'm not sure how. I've tried including a secondary or regex with `|([:digit:]{1,2}$)` but the matching gets greedy.

So desiring matching is:

[image]

Comment: If you have a relatively short list of algorithm IDs, might it be easier to just match to those?

Comment: Not sure, if I understand right, but have a look if [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/323qSg/1) helps.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example ? Do you have a list of all possible algorithms as assumed by G5W ? If yes, can you share it ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the list of all possible algorithms. Put that into the list that I called `TrueNames` and then just look for the algorithm names within `algs`.

```
algs <- c("svmLinear234", "svmLinear25", "C5.05", "C5.053", 
    "gamSpline34", "bagEarth8")

TrueNames = c("svmLinear2", "C5.0", "gamSpline", "bagEarth")
Pat = paste(c(".*(", paste(TrueNames, collapse = "|"), ").*"), collapse="")

sub(Pat, "\\1", algs)

[1] "svmLinear2" "svmLinear2" "C5.0"       "C5.0"       "gamSpline" 
[6] "bagEarth"
```